# How to set a 3-d tensor to 0 according to the value of a 2-d tensor

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a 3-d tensor `P` shaped `(B, N, d)` and a 2-d tensor `Q` shaped `(B,N)`, where values in `Q` are smaller than `d`. I want to set some values in `P` to `0` using the indices from `Q`:

For instance,

```
P = torch.randn(2,3,6)
Q = torch.tensor([[0,3,4], [2,1,3]])
```

How can I set `P[0,0,0]=0; P[0,1,3]=0; P[0,2,4]=0; P[1,0,2]=0; P[1,1,1]=0; P[1,2,3]=0` using `Q` and keep other values in `P` unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is:

```
P[i, j, Q[i, j]] = 0
```

This is the perfect use case for [`torch.Tensor.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_), which has the effect of placing an arbitrary value at designated positions.

We first need the input and indexer to have matching shapes:

```
>>> Q_ = Q[...,None].expand_as(P)
```

And apply the scatter function on `dim=2`, with the *hidden* `value` argument...

```
P.scatter(dim=2, index=Q_, value=0)
tensor([[[0, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7],
         [4, 1, 5, 0, 3, 8],
         [7, 8, 4, 3, 0, 1]],

        [[7, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3],
         [5, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5],
         [6, 3, 5, 0, 7, 2]]])
```